# First argument is wrong when passing __VA_ARGS__

Tags: c, macros, variadic-functions

I'm trying to pass __ VA_ARGS __ to a function. For some reason the first argument is always wrong (seems like an address):

```
#define PRINTF_ERROR(format, ...)  {\
        PrintfError(format, __FUNCTION__, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
}

void PrintfError(const char* format, const char* function, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    printf("%s(): ", function);
    printf(format, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

For example, when trying to print the same variable:
"A = 0x20005524   A = 0x00000007"

Does anybody know why?
Thanks

Comment: `printf` doesn't take a `va_list` -- you probably mean `vprintf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problem here.

First, `va_start` expects the last named parameter of the current function as its second parameter.  In this case that would be `function`.

The second issue is that you're passing a `va_list` into `printf`.  You should be calling `vprintf` instead.

```
void PrintfError(const char* format, const char* function, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, function);   // pass "function" instead of "format"
    printf("%s(): ", function);
    vprintf(format, args);      // call vprintf
    va_end(args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got the order of your parameters wrong. The one you pass to `va_start()` has to be the one before the `...` because it's used to work out where the extra arguments start

So your function should look like this...

```
void PrintfError(const char* function, const char* format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
```

Answer (score 0):

From [`man va_start`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdarg.3.html):

> ```
> void va_start(va_list ap, last);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
> va_start()
> ```
>
> [...]
>   The argument `last` is the name of the last argument before the variable argument list, that is, the last argument of which the calling function knows the type.

So given

```
void PrintfError(const char* format, const char* function, ...)
```

just change

```
  va_start(args, format);
```

to be

```
  va_start(args, function);
```

---

Also this

```
  printf(format, args);
```

(which probably is a typo) should be

```
  vprintf(format, args);
```

---

Unrelated to your question, here

```
#define PRINTF_ERROR(format, ...)  {\
    PrintfError(format, __FUNCTION__, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
}
```

the curly braces are only half the way to make this safe.

Better do

```
#define PRINTF_ERROR(format, ...)  do {\
    PrintfError(format, __FUNCTION__, __VA_ARGS__);\
} while (0)
```

Also no need for the `##`.